# Check if value 50% or more is matched with the needle in haystack in a multidimensional Array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, similarity

I want to check if a value is 50% or more identical in a multidimensional Array as the "needle" i put in.

I got a function that can check if a value is identical in a multidimensional array:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = true) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
    }
```

But i want to return the function true if a given percentage of the value is identical.
I think that i need to integrating something like: `similar_text($value1, $value2, $percent);`

```
if {$percent > 50) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: How do you want to compare the strings? If `$value1 = "Apple";` and `$value2 = "orange";`, how do you want to say they are similar? Like `if("A" == "o") { //Do something }` for each letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would avoid recursive functions where possible

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = true) {
    $eq = 0;
    $diff = 0;
    for($i=0,$n=count($haystack); $i<$n; $i++){
        for($j=0,$m=count($haystack[$i]); $j<$m; $j++){
            if (($strict && $haystack[$i][$j] === $needle) || $haystack[$i][$j] == $needle){
                $eq++;
            } else {
                $diff++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $eq/($eq+$diff);
}
```